# How to fix RpcException: The project new-project does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, asp.net-core-webapi

Using .net core 2+ web api, I'm trying to create a collection in firestore and add documents to it. Initializing the Cloud Firestore works fine and proven by returning an OK result containing the initialized project's id. But when I'm about to create a collection and add a document to it, I'm starting to get an error saying that my project does not exist.

To be able to communicate with firestore through my api, I installed google's Google.Cloud.Firestore (1.0.0-beta20) from NuGet. Also, I already have new-project (new-project is the firebase project name) set up in firebase console. A service key for new-project is also already set up in my environment -- by providing GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with the path of the service key's path. Initially, I had a "Name resolution failure" error but that went away after setting GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER=native in my environment.

Here's how I communicate with firestore.

```cs
var db = FirestoreDb.Create("new-project");

var collectionReference = db.Collection("users");

var docRef1 = collectionReference.Document("alovelace");
var user1 = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "First", "Ada" },
    { "Last", "Lovelace" },
    { "Born", 1815 }
};
await docRef1.SetAsync(user1);
```

Error message is

```
RpcException: Status(StatusCode=NotFound, Detail="The project new-project does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to create a project or https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=new-project to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled.")
```

Stack trace is

```
Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass0_0<TRequest, TResponse>+<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Google.Cloud.Firestore.WriteBatch.CommitAsync(ByteString transactionId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in WriteBatch.cs
Google.Cloud.Firestore.DocumentReference.SetAsync(object documentData, SetOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in DocumentReference.cs
DashApi.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in ValuesController.cs
            var user1 = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "First", "Ada" },
                { "Last", "Lovelace" },
                { "Born", 1815 }
            };
            await docRef1.SetAsync(user1); //THIS IS WHAT TRIGGERS THE ERROR.
lambda_method(Closure , object )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable+Awaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I have followed the docs and is expecting to have a users collection and alovelace document under that collection instead of an error.

Comment: Have you checked those links that are in the exception message?

Comment: @vasily.sib, the first one is just pointing to the console.google.com then asks to create a new project which I already have. The second one redirects me to GCP's firestore UI (both GCP and Firebase consoles have a UI for firestore) which shows me my empty project.

Comment: _"... to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database ..."_ - I thnk this part of message means that your GCP project must not be empty, right? Also _"... Note that Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled."_ - have you check this?

Comment: @vasily.sib, regarding your first question, my GCP is not empty. It has a project named new-project. So when I go to the link referred to in the same sentence, I get redirected to that project. Regarding the second question, I'm not sure how to enable this but I did search for App Engine in GCP and it says there that "Your App Engine application has been created". I'm not sure if that necessarily means that it is enabled.

Comment: not your GCP should not be empty, you GCP **project** named _"new-project"_ should. When you open it within GCP you should see that it contains _"an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database"_ and active App Engine for this database